# Olive oil pricing in Croatia

Tags: food-and-drink, price, croatia

Last year we spent two weeks in a camping resort in Croatia and bought 1 liter of olive oil (bottled) in the resort's supermarket for ~220 kn (~ €29.50 at today's rate).

We realized that the price we paid for this (cheapest) oil was nearly 10 times more than what we would have paid in Germany for the same item. In contrast, other things like wine, milk products etc. were only a little more expensive than elsewhere but relatively normal, and as what you would expect to pay in a resort's market.

We didn't check whether the same high prices occurred in other markets in Croatia, but I think we would have observed the same thing.

Why was that so? In Greece e.g., or other places that produce olive oil we did not observe such high prices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about economics, not travel.

Comment: Voting to re-open since the question is about shopping specifically *while traveling*.

Comment: Which brand of oil was it? You can easily find high quality olive oil in Germany for 30€ or more per liter as well. If you find 'olive oil' for a tenth of that price in Germany, I am pretty sure that it is not really olive oil in the bottle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The premium you paid is due due to buying it in the Resort/Hotel shop.  While that markup is pretty high, it is nearly universal that you will pay noticeably more in the Resort/Hotel shop than on the street.

For most guests, convenience significantly outweighs cost and some guests are captive with no means to easily or safely leave the Resort.

You will also find the markup on certain products varies widely.  This is basic pricing strategy.  People have good idea of what milk or cookies should cost so a 500% markup is very obvious makes it look like the merchant is blatantly overcharging.

Luxury or uncommon items give them more flexibility since many tourists may not know how much 'local premium olive oil' should cost, so they pay whatever the merchant charges.

Answer (score 6):

Here is price example in a sales catalog of [Konzum](https://www.konzum.hr/Katalozi)'s, Croatia's largest supermarket chain.

[image]

[direkt link to the catalog](https://www.konzum.hr/Katalozi/Konzum-katalog-1-2018-cetvrtak-04.sijecanj-2018.-12-00-00-srijeda-10.sijecanj-2018.-12-00-00)

So, the normal price is 55 kn which is about 7,4 euro (or about 10 euro per ltr) which is comparable to prices in German supermarkets.

Comment: So then it's maybe an issue with the ressorts market, and this year I'm going to leave the ressort for the next Konzum...

Comment: But this does not explain the striking high price difference to the ressorts markets olive oil price  compared to the price of other articles as mentioned above.

Comment: You've only seen one price in one ressort. There may be hundreds of equally probable reasons for that high price. No one here can say you which of those reasons is true.